# Eclipse - "No Default Proposals"

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with eclipse kepler. I have a switch - case statement. In first case, it show suggestion code when I press Ctrl+Space but from second case to late, it don't show any more. 
How can I fix this problem. Thank you!
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add the switch case statement you mean in a code block, please? Without the code it is unlikely someone can help you, unless there is a known bug.

Comment: edited. I have tried to reinstall eclipse, remove all plugin but it have still not worked.

Comment: Ah, so if you type ´mChannelRequest.´ in the line below ´case REQUEST_CHANNEL´ you get codecompletion and if you type ´mChannelRequest.´ in the line below ´case RETURN_CHANNEL:´you don't get code completion, right?

Comment: It don't show suggestion code when i use Ctrl+Space from case RETURN_CHANNEL

Comment: Sorry, my reputation < 10, so i can't post images